# Can't Delete Closed Question Unless With Delete Votes

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-questions

I get that you can delete your post within 24 hours or with 3 votes for deletion. My question is currently closed: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247544/is-wikipedia-a-reliable-source-for-an-answer, has an answer and been viewed 107 times in 5 days. So I want to delete my post since it is not been received well. But I can't yet with 3 delete votes from ***other*** users can. Why can't the author delete his own question if delete votes can?

Comment: you should be able to delete that question. What error or message do you get when you try?

Comment: This question already has answers and cannot be deleted. Please flag it for moderator attention instead

Comment: I flagged that post so it can be migrated to History of Science and Mathematics Meta. That flag is still active.

Comment: @Shog9 the answer has +2/-2 is this a bug that the OP can't delete the question?

Comment: Don't worry about deleting stuff from Meta -- it's all good. Why not let your questions stick around so that they can remind (you and) others about why certain things are the way they are?

Comment: Because I want to